# Is there a way to combine two Docker base images in a single container and build with kaniko?

Tags: java, mongodb, docker, kubernetes, kaniko

The use case is such that I need both JDK and Mongo images in a single container, the java process starts up the Mongo daemon process.

Comment: It's unusual to actually need to two separate processes in a single container like that; standard practice is to run your application and database in two separate containers, maybe orchestrated with Docker Compose.  More broadly, no, it's not possible to combine two images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the minimum Dockerfile that bake JRE 11 to the mongo image.

```
FROM mongo:latest

# Replace the version if desired
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install openjdk-11-jre-headless -y

# Install your app and stuffs here...

# Override for your own command
CMD ["java","-version"]
```

Build the image `docker build -t mongodb-java .`

Test the image `docker run -t --rm mongodb-java` will output the JRE version.

Test the image `docker run -t --rm mongodb-java mongo --version` will output the MongoDB version.

You can then follow Kaniko [steps](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#running-kaniko-in-docker) to build the image.

Answer (score 2):

You are not needed to use two base images. just use one of the base image jdk/mongo and then using binaries install mongo/jdk on top of the chosen base image.